# remove div tags and replace some of them by br tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the next text:

`fffffff<div>hhhhh</div><div>kh</div>`

1) I want to remove only div tags.

2) If the div tag is not in the first of the string and not in the end of the string, replace it by `<br/>`

3) `</div><div>` should be replaced by one div.

---

**examples:**

1) `fffffff<div>hhhhh</div><div>kh</div>` -> `fffffff<br/>hhhhh<br/>kh`

The `</div>` tag at the end of the string was not replaced cause it's at the end of the string.

2) `<div>fffffff</div><div>hhhhh</div><div>kh</div>` -> `fffffff<br/>hhhhh<br/>kh`

You can assume that there is no text something like:

`<div><div><div><div><div></div><div>text</div><div></div>`

---

**Find all html tags:**

`replace(/<[^>]*>/g, "<br/>")`

But it replaces all the html tags by `<br/>`

Comment: And what have you done already to complete that task?

Comment: @Justinas The last line shows what they've tried so far

Comment: I tried this one also:
text.replace(/<div>.*<\/div>/s, "")

text.replace("</div><div>", "</div><br /><div>").replace(/<[^>]*>/g, "")

Comment: Never parse html with regexp. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: you can try this <div>?.*<div>.*?<\/div>?unmatch|.*?<\/div>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To match your examples :

```
var str = "fffffff<div>hhhhh</div><div>kh</div>";
if(str.indexOf("<div>") === 0){
    str = str.substring(5);
}
if(str.slice(-6) === "</div>"){
    str = str.substring(0,str.length - 6);
}
str = str.replace(/<\/div><div>/g,"<br/>");
str = str.replace(/<div>/g,"<br/>");
```

but to match your third rule you should to change

```
str = str.replace(/<\/div><div>/g,"<br/>");
```

by

```
str = str.replace(/<\/div><div>/g,"<div>");
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use **[`html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/)** and **[`replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)** for that

```js
$('.c').html(function(i, v) {
  return v.replace(/^([\w\s]+)(<div>.*?<\/div>)/, '$1<br/>$2')
    //-^- For first div
    .replace(/<div>(.*?)<\/div>\s*$/, '$1')
    //-^- For removing div at ending
    .replace(/<div>(.*?)<\/div>/g, '$1<br/>')
    //-^-For removing other div
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class=c>
  <div>fffffff</div>
  <div>hhhhh</div>
  <div>kh</div>
</div>
<div class=c>
  fffffff
  <div>hhhhh</div>
  <div>kh</div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you, but this text:

"fffffff<div>hhhhh</div><div>kh</div>"
is replaced to:
"fffffffhhhhh<br>kh<br>"

I think you didn't see requirement number 2..

Comment: Isn't that what you wanted? @Alon

Comment: I think I understand what wasn't clear..
The div at the start of the string means that it's found at index 0.
So the first div in my example should be replaced to `<br/>`

Comment: I'm sorry but I tried the updated answer and "fffffff<div>hhhhh</div><div>kh</div>" was replaced to "fffffffhhhhh</div><div>kh" instead of "fffffff<br/>hhhhh<br/>kh"

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Ht6Ym/3462/

It doesn't work yet, I think that you can continue my solution..

Comment: I think this it the solution (I use your solution also, so update it and I marked you solution..) Thank you very much!
http://jsfiddle.net/Ht6Ym/3463/